# Destroy All Previous Activities After Specific Activity is Open

Tags: android, android-activity

This is the scenario

`Activity A` -> `Activity B` -> `Activity C` -> `Activity D` (I would like to destroy Activity A, B, and C after `Activity D` is launched.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
//use finish with intent
FirstActivity.this.finish();

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityC.this, ActivityD.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

**FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK**

> If set, this activity will become the start of a new task on this
> history stack. A task (from the activity that started it to the next
> task activity) defines an atomic group of activities that the user can
> move to. Tasks can be moved to the foreground and background; all of
> the activities inside of a particular task always remain in the same
> order. See Tasks and Back Stack for more information about tasks.
>
> This flag is generally used by activities that want to present a
> "launcher" style behavior: they give the user a list of separate
> things that can be done, which otherwise run completely independently
> of the activity launching them.
>
> When using this flag, if a task is already running for the activity
> you are now starting, then a new activity will not be started;
> instead, the current task will simply be brought to the front of the
> screen with the state it was last in. See FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK
> for a flag to disable this behavior.
>
> This flag can not be used when the caller is requesting a result from
> the activity being launched.

**FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK**

> If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will
> cause any existing task that would be associated with the activity to
> be cleared before the activity is started. That is, the activity
> becomes the new root of an otherwise empty task, and any old
> activities are finished. This can only be used in conjunction with
> FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.

Comment: if you clearing all activities then you don't need `ActivityC.this.finish();`

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` with `Intent` :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), D.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: When I am already at Activity C. I called the code `Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), D.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);` But when I hit the back button. I still come back to `Activity C`. Thanks for answering though

Comment: Yes You can go to the activity C but your activity A, B will be finished

Comment: Use : Activity_C activity = new Activity_C();
        activity.finish();  in your Activity D OnCreate() Method

Answer (score 3):

Use these lines to clear the activity stack when the Activity C is launched:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(PresentActivityName.this, D.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
```

Comment: if you clearing all activities then you don't need `ActivityC.this.finish();`