# How to use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK in Android 11

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

I have been trying to use the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` flags.

In Android 10 I had no problem but when I use them in Android 11 it doesn't work as expected.

code:

```
val intent = Intent(activity, VideoActivity::class.java).apply {
    putExtra(EPISODE_ITEM_EXTRA, episodeItem)
    putExtra(ANALYTICS_TAG_EXTRA, analyticsTag)
    flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

}
activity.startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: And what happened instead?

Comment: when I use that code and test it on android 10 it does what is expected, but when I run it on android 11 the activity shows a black screen

Comment: What was expected?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34525281/destroy-all-previous-activities-after-specific-activity-is-open

Comment: Please read "[ask]". Titles should be a simple statement describing the problem to be fixed.